# Gimp won't start up due to a missing libgegl 

Tags: gimp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GIMP won't open any more](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106470/gimp-wont-open-any-more)

I currently run Ubuntu 11.10, I installed Gimp 2.6.12, it installed fine. I went to click on the Gimp icon after installation and nothing happens. I open a picture and select Gimp as the application to use on it and nothing happens. I uninstalled and reinstalled the software and the same thing, icon is there and nothing happens when I click on it. Any help would be appreciated.

When I open it in a terminal I get this error:

```
gimp: error while loading shared libraries: libgegl-0.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Open it from a terminal and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: How do you open it up from the terminal? I know how to operate the terminal, but not sure what you mean by open it up.

Comment: ok figured it out, here is the error:

Comment: gimp: error while loading shared libraries: libgegl-0.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you try reinstalling libgegl? In terminal: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgegl-0.0-0`.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/106470/gimp-wont-open-any-more